# WPF Use transforms to display an app level Overlay

Tags: wpf, xaml, rendertransform, layouttransform

I have a `FrameworkElement` nested as follows (ideally the solution shouldn't depend on a particular path though):

```
Window=>Grid=>ScrollViewer=>Grid[1]=>Grid[2].
```

I want my Grid[2] to be displayed as it would be an immediate child of `Grid` (or `Window`) with `Margin=0` and both alignments set to `Stretch` (i.e. `Dock=Fill` kind of thing), using any of the transforms (since it's a form I need the buttons to remain clickable etc, so I'd favor `LayoutTransform` ). Obviously I want Grid[2] to become the topmost control.

Wonder if it's doable and if so what's the best way of doing that? Please note I can't re-assign Grid[2] parent using the behavior or anything I want everything to be done just by applying a transform.

Update 1 - Grid[2] has got no size, so it'd be nice if it can stretch as the window gets resized.

Comment: You want `Grid[2]` to always be shown? Regardless of scroll in the scroll viewer? If so, why is it in the scroll viewer? Why can't you change the layout? And finally, what is the end result that you're looking for?

Comment: Nope, I want it to be shown in response to a certain action (Command handler) of my VM, so I can execute code. The end result is Grid[2] should look like its parent was re-assigned to Grid with the only difference that it wasn't:)